# installing pylinkgrammar for windows

Tags: python-3.x, link-grammar

I am trying to install link grammar on windows for python using "pip install pylinkgrammar" command. I am getting an error which says "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 required." Then I installed Visual C++ Build tools and I get the same error. Can somebody help me?

Comment: A couple of years after this is still the same complex installation process. I could not find any precompiled version that could work and after installing software after software, I will give up. Too bad, this library was looking useful.

Answer (score 0):

i too am facing the same issue, after installing "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" and  "Visual C++ Build tools", installing  "pip install pylinkgrammar" throws error saying "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 failed with exit status 2", i think its not compatible with python version 3.

Answer (score 0):

The current pylinkgrammar is for a very old version of link-grammar (version 4). It is also only for python-2.

The current version of link-grammar is 5.3.16.
It includes python-3 bindings (and also the same bindings for python-2), but note that it is a different one than is used in pylinkgrammar.
You can download the latest version from its [project page](https://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/).
It is not a binary distribution, so you have to compile it.
You currently need at least Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 for that.
You will also need to install python-3 and Swig.
See the MSVC14/README.md there.

The link-grammar development package is in [GitHub](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar). If you encounter problems in compiling the package, find bugs, or have ideas for enhancements, you can open an issue there.

For general questions about link-grammar you can use its [discussion-group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/link-grammar).